# Inherit from QBufferDataGenerator

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, qt5, pyqt5, qt3d

First of all my setup:

**python3**

**requirements.txt**

```
PyQt5>=5.12
pyqt3d>=5.12
pyopengl
```

**example.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.Qt3DCore import *
from PyQt5.Qt3DRender import *

class SomeDataGenerator(QBufferDataGenerator):
    def __init__(self, some_bytes):
        super().__init__()
        self._bytes = some_bytes

    def __call__(self):
        return self._bytes

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self._bytes == other._bytes)

    def __neq__(self, other):
        return not (self._bytes == other._bytes)

    def id(self):
        return functorTypeId(SomeDataGenerator)


someBytes = QByteArray()
someBuffer = QBuffer(QBuffer.VertexBuffer)
someDataGenerator = SomeDataGenerator(someBytes)
someBuffer.setDataGenerator(someDataGenerator)
```

And output as I run it:

```
$ python3 example.py
...
TypeError: PyQt5.Qt3DRender.QBufferDataGenerator cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

So the question is how can I call `QBuffer::setDataGenerator`?

The big thing I want to do: draw points or whatever with `Qt3D` via `PyQt5` bindings.

Comment: Seems to be a pretty obvious bug, since [QBufferDataGenerator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbufferdatagenerator.html#details) is specifically designed to be subclassed. Report it on the [pyqt mailing list](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: @ekhumoro, do you have any idea, how I could do any workaround for this?

Comment: By using [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3drender-qbuffer.html#details), apparently.